# Get nested properties values

Tags: c#

I have a class with 25 properties. Some of these properties are list of custom objects.

e.g. the `X3` property in object of class `A` is `List<>` of objects of class `B`.

```
class A 
{
    public int X1 { get; set; }

    public string X2 { get; set; }

    public List<B> X3 { get; set; }
}
```

B class also has public properties:

```
class B
{
    public int Y1 { get; set; }

    public int Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to iterate over the properties of an object of class `A` so as to get the non-null values of properties and the properties of any nested objects in the list?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a dictionary? Iterating over properties can be done with reflection, but in many cases it is a code smell if you find yourself treating your classes as property bags.

Comment: Should that be `public List<B> X3 { get; set; }`?

Comment: this can't possibly compile.. don't you get a `Type expected` error here
` public List<> X3 { get; set; }`

Comment: Adding to Wai's fine comment, OP's code **wont compile**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the properties of a type by using the built-in reflection API of .NET. Quick and dirty example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var a = new A()
  {
    X1 = 1,
    X2 = "2",
    X3 = new List<B> { new B { Y1 = 5, Y2 = 7 } }
  };

  PrintProperties(a);
}

private static void PrintProperties(object obj)
{
  foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    var propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
    var value = prop.GetValue(obj);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} [{2}]", prop.Name, value, propertyType);

    if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(propertyType))
    {
      var list = (IList)value;

      foreach (var entry in list)
      {
        PrintProperties(entry);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (prop.PropertyType.Namespace != "System")
      {
        PrintProperties(value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you were already told, such code shouldn't be used when your types are known at compile time.